# How to pause system time on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, time, code

I am intereseted in any method of making sure that functions such as the C++ `now()` return the same thing when called multiple times in a row.

The ideal solution is reversible and works on a Windows 10 laptop (CMOS battery not removable).

Comment: This doesn’t make a lot of sense. `now()` returns the current system time and the current system time is always progressing. If you want a function to return the same value every time you call it then make your own new function. Wrap the `now()` function if necessary.

Comment: @Appleoddity well, this is exactly what I am interested in: a way of stopping the progression of the current system time.

Comment: If you're using code and the `now()` function or whatever and when you call that function you set a variable with that time, and then you just reference that same variable later on and it will retain the same time as long as you code the logic accordingly so you set the variable like that and ensure your additional logic doesn't change it. When you call `now()` it will get "current" time, so set the first `now()` current time as a variable that will not change and just reference that variable rather than using `now()` on subsequent runs of that logic.

Comment: I.e declare `my_now()` and code it as `if testing, return same value, else call now()`

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill, it is not a question specific to either programming or software development as the example with the now() function was just a description of one of the results of the action or set of actions I am looking for. Otherwise said, I am looking for any method of stopping the system time on a Windows 10 laptop, which is very much a topic concerning computer hardware and/or computer software. Why I am looking for this should be irrelevant to the on/off-topic discussion.

Comment: It's still a programming issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I am looking for a way of pausing the system clock in order to study the effect it has on games with time-based mechanics, such as Dragon Age: Inquisition. I do not have access to the DA:I source files, nor am I a developer for said game. Does this change the question from a programming issue to a gaming issue?